# Static instances in an android application

Tags: android, class, service, android-activity, static

FYI: I'm not a pro, so this might be easy to solve I just couldn't find a solution till now.

Following scenario. I have an Android application. In the main activity I initialize a static instance of a class to take care of the communication via WebSockets, then I start a service that is using this static instance.

1. Now, when I close the activity, I'm keeping the service running in the background (with a partial wake lock), the problem is, when I destroy the service later on, the static instance sometimes remains active until I remove the app from the "cached processes".
2. When I start the activity again, I have again, a new static instance initialized.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

> the problem is, when I destroy the service later on, the static instance sometimes remains active until I remove the app from the "cached processes".

If you do not want this, do something to stop it from `onDestroy()` of your service. Or, do not make it a static in the first place, but rather have it be part of the service itself.

Comment: I am closing the connection in onDestroy(), removing all listeners I created etc. I cannot put it in the service itself because I need to access the connection from multiple classes and services.

Comment: @i--: "I am closing the connection in onDestroy(), removing all listeners I created etc." -- then if "the static instance sometimes remains active", you either have a bug in your `onDestroy()`, or you are not stopping the service when you think you are.